# checkboxes to enable their respective text fielsd and get input values from user in each field

Tags: java, fxml

I'm trying to create code where a checkbox will enable its related textfield, and then the user can input a value in the textfield which will be used for later calculation (there are 3 checkboxes, 1 for each field with the same idea).  However, I'm getting an error when parsing the double value... see part of the code below.  Thanks for the help in advance.

When I remove this line: double usb = Double.parseDouble(txtusb.getText());
The code works and the field is disabled/enabled just fine, but I get an error if the line is enabled, then again disable the field before even putting in any value.  Not sure how to go about this...

```
@FXML
private void chkusb1(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(chkusb.isSelected()==true)
    {
    txtusb.setDisable(false);
    double usb = Double.parseDouble(txtusb.getText());
    }
    else
    {
        txtusb.setDisable(true);
    }
```

}

The idea is to take the 3 different fields (enabled/disabled by checkbox), calculate each one based on the value and then output a total of the 3 different values.

Comment: When you call `double usb = ...`, the text field is probably still empty, and an empty string cannot be parsed as a double. You should not be executing that line there, nor should you be disabling the field in that method. All of that should be done AFTER the user has entered all of the values in the fields.

Comment: Also, never compare a boolean result to true or false. Just use `if (xxx)` or `if ( !xxx)`

Comment: Thanks Fred, so enabling the field like this is sufficient?

}
    if(chkusb.isSelected()==true)
    {
    txtusb.setDisable(false);
}

can you suggest a place/way to get the user's input to a variable?

Comment: `if ( chkusb,isSelected() ) {...}`. And use an event handler in the text field to detect when its content is modified

Comment: Thanks Fred, much appreciated.